# angular ui-router finding issue on refresh the page

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

In my application, when `auth` success, I am redirecting to `/users`. It works fine, and I am in users page too. But when I refresh the page, I am getting an error as:

> Cannot GET /users

What does this mean?

As well my base location is `/` which is for `login` page, as well when user enter the path as `/login` - I am not redirecting to `/`. What is the issue?

Here is my `router` config :

```
(function(){    
    "use strict";    
    angular.module('meanOffice')
        .config(routeConfig);


    function routeConfig( $locationProvider, $stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider ){

        $stateProvider
            .state('login', {
                url:'/',
                templateUrl : 'app/views/pages/login/login.html',
                controller  : 'mainController as main'
            })
            .state('users', {
                url:'/users', //refresh getting error
                templateUrl : 'app/views/pages/users/users.html',
                controller  : 'usersController as users'
            })


        $locationProvider.html5Mode({
            enabled: true,
            requireBase: false
        });


        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');//when type '/login' throw error

    }

})();
```

Comment: Could you show what `Console` of browser writes to you?  and write, please, about the full content of error.

Answer (score 1):

This means your server is not set up correctly.

In order to use HTML5 mode, all requests need to direct to your entrypoint.
For more information on how to set up your server, please read: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode

Comment: I am using `node` as my server. if you have any specific approach please let me know

Comment: `node` on itself cannot be used as a server. I'm guessing you're using `express` as it is the most common server. You can check "Express Rewrites" on the linked page to see if your setup is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Setup your express app:

```
app.route('/*').get(function(req, res) { 
    return res.sendFile(path.join(config.root, 'index.html')); 
});
```